# Hive Query to find the name in EMAIL ID

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

How to extract from "abc" from abc@gmail.com using hive query?
**select substr(email,replace(find("@"),length,""));**
We can use INSTR also.

Answer (score -1):

substr(email,replace(INSTR("@"),length,""));

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).